# How to write a git hook to pull every push?

Tags: git, githooks

How can I create a git-hook so that whenever I push my local repo, another local repo, at some other machine, will pull it right away?

I want to update the other repo automatically on every push I make.
Should I use a 3rd party software for that?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to run `git push` on computer A to send the latest changes to computer B and a third computer, C, somehow, to learn about this and pull the changes from B?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want